# How to convert vertices to points with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I made a Geometry Node that allows me to make a Fibonacci Spiral for a project that I am working on. However, I need to instance points on every vertex position and get rid of the edges.

[image: The spiral created by the Geometry Node]

[image: The Node Tree itself]

Do the Geometry Nodes have any way to do that or do I need to rebuild parts of it?

---

Turns out I might have had some errors in my Node Tree.
[Gorgious](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKYgH.png) has pointed out that the Point [Instance Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlTDK.png) is supposed to work.

This method did not work for me until now but I have also edited my question once because I had another error in the Node Tree I needed to correct.
This seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: Use the [Point Instance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/point_instance.html) node ?

Comment: Weird, I tried that and it never worked.
I did change some parts of the Node tree since I submitted the question so maybe I fixed another problem without realizing it.

Comment: Did you achieve what you were trying to do ?

Comment: I only now realized that the answer I gave to my post explaining that this has been solved was deleted. Yes this did solve my problem. It seems I had another mistake in my Tree.